# What are the brackets for in SingularDTV crowdfunding contract

Tags: solidity, tokens

I can't figure out what the brackets are for in this line of code, initializing the SingularDTVFund:

```
SingularDTVFund constant singularDTVFund = SingularDTVFund({{SingularDTVFund}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solidity compiler won't take it, as is. Without delving into their code, looks like handlebars to be interpolated by javascript before compiling and deploying.

{{SingularDTVFund}} probably going to be replaced by a deployed contract address in the migration process. So, it's saying SingularDTVFund(AtSomeAddress). More flexible than hardcoding 0x123...